# Animated transition for Knockoutjs virtual element control flow bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, transition

What modifications are required to make all the child div elements in the following code slide up or down instead of just the first child div element as coded here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JdG5m/

HTML:

```
<!-- ko fadeIf: show -->
<div data-bind="text: name" style="display: none"></div>
<div data-bind="text: name2" style="display: none"></div>
<!-- /ko -->

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: show" /> Show
```

JS:

```
(function() {
    var getFirstRealElement = function(element) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(ko.virtualElements.childNodes(element) || [], function(el) {
             return el.nodeType === 1; 
        });
    };

    var makeTemplateValueAccessor = function(valueAccessor) {
        return function() { return { 'if': valueAccessor(), 'templateEngine': ko.nativeTemplateEngine.instance } };
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.fadeIf = {
        init: ko.bindingHandlers['if'].init,
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                child = getFirstRealElement(element),
                updater = function() {
                   ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element, makeTemplateValueAccessor(valueAccessor), allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext); 
                   $(getFirstRealElement(element)).slideDown('slow');
                };

            if (child) {
                $(child).slideUp('slow', updater);                         
            } else {
                updater();
            }
        }
    };


    ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.fadeIf = true;
})();

var viewModel = {
    name: ko.observable("Bob"),
    name2: ko.observable("Mary"),
    show: ko.observable(false)     
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your `updater` method to select all child nodes rather than just the first child by changing this line:

```
$(getFirstRealElement(element)).slideDown('slow');
```

to:

```
$(ko.virtualElements.childNodes(element)).slideDown('slow');
```

So your `updater` method will now look like:

```
updater = function() {
ko.bindingHandlers.template.update([...params]); 
    $(ko.virtualElements.childNodes(element)).slideDown('slow');
 };
```

Here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/JdG5m/1/

Comment: That appears to do the trick however for more than two divs it doesn't slide all of them up so I changed: $(child).slideUp('slow', updater) to $(ko.virtualElements.childNodes(element)).slideUp('slow', updater); but it only toggles the interaction once. http://jsfiddle.net/JdG5m/3/